# Silverlight - Simple DataGridComboBoxColumn Binding to Y/N values

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am trying to bind just two values to my DataGrid's DataGridComboBoxColumn with "Y" and "N" values.  What is the recommended way to do this?  Via a local resource? A List property on the VM?

For this column, a User basically just has two options that can be entered, either a "Y" or a "N".

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a boolean property on the ViewModel and bind to that. Then I'd use a converter in the binding to have it say "Y" or "N" instead of true/false or whatever the default is.